# python Redis Connections

Tags: python, redis

I am using Redis server with python.

My application is multithreaded ( I use 20 - 32 threads per process) and I also
I run the app in different machines.

I have noticed that sometimes Redis cpu usage is 100% and Redis server became unresponsive/slow.

I would like to use per application 1 Connection Pool of 4 connections in total.
So for example, if I run my app in 20 machines at maximum, there should be 
20*4 = 80 connections to the redis Server.

```
POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(max_connections=4, host='192.168.1.1', db=1, port=6379)
R_SERVER = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)

class Worker(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            key = R_SERVER.randomkey()
            if not key: break
            value = R_SERVER.get(key)


    def _do_something(self, value):
        # do something with value
        pass

if __name__ = '__main__':
    num_threads = 20
    workers = [Worker() for _ in range(num_threads)]
    for w in workers:
       w.join()
```

The above code should run the 20 threads that get a connection from the connection pool of max size 4 when a command is executed.

When the connection is released?

According to this code (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/master/redis/client.py):

```
    #### COMMAND EXECUTION AND PROTOCOL PARSING ####
def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
    "Execute a command and return a parsed response"
    pool = self.connection_pool
    command_name = args[0]
    connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
    try:
        connection.send_command(*args)
        return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
    except ConnectionError:
        connection.disconnect()
        connection.send_command(*args)
        return self.parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
    finally:
        pool.release(connection)
```

After the execution of each command, the connection is released and gets back to the pool

Can someone verify that I have understood the idea correct and the above example code will work as described?

Because when I see the redis connections, there are always more than 4.

EDIT: I just noticed in the code that the function has a return statement before the finally. What is the purpose of finally then?

Comment: The finally block gets executed whether their was an exception or not.  This is a DRY use case.

Comment: You mention that the Redis server sometimes becomes unresponsive. Are you using Windows? If so, the Windows version does save the database to disk asynchronously, which will cause Redis to hang until it has finished.

Comment: Even in a unix environment, saving can be expensive.  If you're using the RDB dump serialization strategy, Redis forks a copy of the in memory DB to write out.  If your DB size is > 1/2 available memory, bad things happen when it tries to do this.  If that's the issue, try using the AOF strategy, or turning off serialization.

Comment: You shall detect cause of non-responsivness. It is not very likely   that larger pool of connections would resolve your troubles as Redis by design always runs in one process, others have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew Scragg mentioned, the finally clause is executed at the end of the test. In this particular case it serves to release the connection back to the pool when finished with it instead of leaving it hanging open.

As to the unresponsiveness, look to what your server is doing. What is the memory limit of your Redis instance? How often are you saving to disk? Are you running on a Xen based VM such as an AWS instance? Are you running replication, and if so how many slaves and are they in a good state or are they frequently calling for a full resync of data? Are any of your commands "save"?

You can answer some of these questions by using the command line interface. For example
`redis-cli info persistence` will tell you information about the process of saving to disk, `redis-cli info memory` will tell you about your memory consumption.

When obtaining the persistence information you want to specifically look at `rdb_last_bgsave_status` and `rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec`. These will tell you if the last save was successful and how long it took. The longer it takes the higher the chances are you are running into resource issues and the higher the chance you will encounter slowdowns which can appear as unresponsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Final block will always run though there is an return statement before it. You may have a look at redis-py/connection.py , pool.release(connection) only put the connection to available-connections pool, So the connection is still alive. 
   About redis server cpu usage, your app will always send request and has no breaks or sleep, so it just use more and more cpus , but not memory . and cpu usage has no relation with open file numbers.